# finger service not getting enabled in my router(cisco packet tracer)

Tags: networking, cisco, router

i tried enabling 'ip finger' command in my router, but it isnt' working, someone please help

```
Router#config terminal 
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#ip finger
                   ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Comment: finger is a legacy protocol and this day and age there is no reason to support and enable it anymore, which might the reason it is simply not available